# Compile C for Windows with MinGW

Tags: c, windows, gcc, compilation, mingw

I installed the latest version of **MinGW** and trying to compile the project:

```
\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -O3 -flto -Wall -msse src/*.c -o noname -lm -lpthread
```

But nothing happens. No errors, no exe files, nothing.

I am not familiar with Windows in terms of compilation.
This is a simple console application that is compilable on Ubuntu without problems with the same command.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Add ".exe" to output filename and maybe try backslash `... src\*.c -o noname.exe ...`? or change to `src` directory and try `... -msse *.c -o ..\noname.exe ...`

Comment: Try a single file HelloWorld first. If main.c, compiled, does not result in an exe it is more easily debugged. I.e. simplify by getting rid of asterisks in your command line.

Comment: @Yunnosch compiling a single file is the same result - nothing happens... And I ran it without asterisks

Comment: @pmg did it, nothing changes...

Comment: Simply further. Your only goal at first is running a HelloWorld. No fancy command line switches. If that does not work try `\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe --version`.

Comment: @Yunnosch compiling simple HelloWorld without any flags does not work either. --version returns gcc.exe (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5) 8.2.0. What could be wrong with that?

Comment: If you set the path to gcc.exe with the `$PATH` variable, you do not need to include the full path to gcc in every compiling command. Maybe this could be an issue. Did you set `$PATH` to `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe` like it is described here: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Install_the_MinGW_GCC_Compiler_Suite?

Comment: Where do you expect the output (i.e. an exe file) to appear? Next to the .c? In the cwd? Next to the gcc.exe?

Comment: Lets turn around the experiments. Instead of trying to get it working, lets try to make it fail visibly. I propose to compile a .c file with the following content `#error Definitly gets compiled!`.

Comment: I can reproduce a similar behaviour (no output, no created files), but I do get an error dialog, concerning a missing dll. Can you confirm that you do NOT get any popup or other problem notification of that kind?

Comment: Please add the option `-v` to your command line, this gives you some verbose output of what is going on. Post the command and its output by [edit]ing your question.